# JDBC if a string exist in a database

Tags: sql, jdbc

I am trying to find where a specific string exist in a database (all tables). I have the following code:

```
 DatabaseMetaData md = con.getMetaData();
           ResultSet rs = md.getTables(null, null, "%", null);
           while (rs.next()) {
                stm = con.createStatement();
                String sql;
                sql = "SELECT * FROM "+rs.getString(3)+"WHERE F01 = '0000000000998'";
                rs2 = stm.executeQuery(sql);
                while(rs2.next()){                   
                System.out.println(rs.getString(3));
             }                    
           }
```

The problem is in some of the tables F01 doesn't exist, so it throws an exception. Is there any way that even without specifying the column I can search through the whole table?

Comment: You need to get the metadata of each table, first check if contains that particular column. If yes then execute the query. look at the api for [metadata](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/DatabaseMetaData.html)

Comment: I see, I am using Microsoft SQL. I was wondering if there is a way that I can check the entry without specifying the column. For now this would work but probably if I want to search something else in a different column it would be much faster to just change the query and it gives me the table.

Answer (score 1):

which database you are using.

Look over this discussion post. you may get good ideas about how to make sure column exists before you call your check
http://www.coderanch.com/t/299298/JDBC/databases/Oracle-describe-table-jdbc

For oracle
you can check these queries

> select COLUMN_NAME, DATA_LENGTH, DATA_TYPE from user_tab_columns where Lower(table_name) = 'product'
>   select table_name, COLUMN_NAME, DATA_LENGTH, DATA_TYPE from user_tab_columns where upper(column_name) = 'PRODUCTID'

therefore your call should be something like this

> select table_name from user_tab_columns where upper(column_name) = 'F01'
>   and then 
>   SELECT * FROM "+rs.getString(1)+"WHERE F01 = '0000000000998'

as you see I am using LOWER and UPPER, you need to make sure you include them, reason as you can understand even though SQL is not case sensitive in its statements, but the value for which conditional check is happening is case sensitive.

Comment: I see, I am using Microsoft SQL. I was wondering if there is a way that I can check the entry without specifying the column. For now this would work but probably if I want to search something else in a different column it would be much faster to just change the query and it gives me the table.

Comment: all DB servers have different schema, and such querying will be dependent on the particular DB server type

Answer (score 0):

The following Java code loops through each VARCHAR/NVARCHAR column in each table and performs a `SELECT TOP 1` on that column to see if it gets a hit:

```java
import java.sql.*;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class JDBCQuery {

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        String textToSearchFor = "Gord";  // test data
        System.out.println(String.format("The value '%s' was found in the following locations:", textToSearchFor));

        Connection conn = null;
        PreparedStatement ps = null;
        try {
            Class.forName("sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver");
            String connectionString = 
                    "jdbc:odbc:Driver={SQL Server};" + 
                    "Server=.\\SQLEXPRESS;" +
                    "Trusted_Connection=yes;" +
                    "Database=myDb";
            conn = DriverManager.getConnection(connectionString);

            DatabaseMetaData md = conn.getMetaData();
            ResultSet mdrs = md.getTables(null, null, "%", new String[] { "TABLE" });
            List<String> tableList = new ArrayList<String>();
            while (mdrs.next()) {
                tableList.add(String.format("[%s].[%s].[%s]", mdrs.getString(1), mdrs.getString(2), mdrs.getString(3)));
                // i.e., [catalogName].[schemaName].[tableName]
            }
            mdrs.close();
            for (String tableName : tableList) {
                Statement stmt = conn.createStatement();
                stmt.execute("SELECT * FROM " + tableName + " WHERE 0=1");
                ResultSet rs0 = stmt.getResultSet();
                ResultSetMetaData rsmd = rs0.getMetaData();
                List<String> columnList = new ArrayList<String>();
                for (int colIndex = 1; colIndex <= rsmd.getColumnCount(); colIndex++) {
                    switch (rsmd.getColumnType(colIndex)) {
                        case java.sql.Types.VARCHAR:
                        case java.sql.Types.NVARCHAR:
                            columnList.add("[" + rsmd.getColumnName(colIndex) + "]");
                            break;
                    }
                }
                rs0.close();
                stmt.close();
                for (String columnName : columnList) {
                    String psSql = String.format("SELECT TOP 1 * FROM %s WHERE %s = ?", tableName, columnName);
                    ps = conn.prepareStatement(psSql);
                    ps.setString(1, textToSearchFor);
                    ResultSet rs1 = ps.executeQuery();
                    if (rs1.next()) {
                        System.out.println(String.format("column %s in %s", columnName, tableName));
                    }
                    rs1.close();
                    ps.close();
                }
            }
        } catch( Exception e ) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            try {
                if (ps != null) {
                    ps.close();
                }
                if (conn != null) {
                    conn.close();
                }
            } catch( Exception e ) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The results look like this;

```
The value 'Gord' was found in the following locations:
column [textCol] in [myDb].[dbo].[linkedTable]
column [FirstName] in [myDb].[dbo].[myContacts]
```